# Using Google OAuth2 and personal rest api

Tags: java, api, rest, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

How would you go about (if possible) using google OAuth2 authentication to access to gain an access token which would allow you access to your own api (one i am building).

In my research I have come across many examples and information about using the access token to use with google's api's but not my own.

The aim is to have a use authentication to the client with a google account, at which point they are then given access to call my api (with the access token provided by google OAuth 2.0)

This is the kind of setup I am looking for.

[Using OAuth 2.0 to allow access to API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNcxM.png)

Without been too specific this would be for a java based rest api.

Again is this possible and if so, any tips or references to material which describes best practices/approaches to do this would me much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at Spring oauth2 project which is well documented and easy to use. http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html